# Custom PinEntryView - default symbols

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have a custom EditText providig PinEntry functionality looking like this:

```
class PinEntryView : EditText {

private var mSpace = 15f
private var mCharSize = 0f
private var mNumChars = 4f
private var mLineSpacing = 8f
private val XML_NAMESPACE_ANDROID = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
private var mClickListener: View.OnClickListener? = null
private var mLineStroke = 1f
private var mLinesPaint: Paint? = null
private var mOnPinEnteredListener: OnPinEnteredListener? = null

private fun updateColorForLines(next: Boolean) {
    if (isFocused) {
        mLinesPaint!!.color = getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent)
        if (next) {
            mLinesPaint!!.color = getColor(context, R.color.edit_text_background)
        }
    } else {
        mLinesPaint!!.color = getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent)
    }
}

constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
    init(context, attrs)
}

constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet,
    defStyleAttr: Int
) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    init(context, attrs)
}

private fun init(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) {
    val multi = context.resources.displayMetrics.density

    mLineStroke *= multi
    mLinesPaint = Paint(paint)
    mLinesPaint!!.strokeWidth = mLineStroke

    mSpace *= multi
    mLineSpacing *= multi
    val mMaxLength = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(
        XML_NAMESPACE_ANDROID,
        "maxLength",
        6
    )

    paint.color = getColor(context, android.R.color.white)

    mNumChars = mMaxLength.toFloat()

    super.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(
        object : ActionMode.Callback {
            override fun onPrepareActionMode(
                mode: ActionMode,
                menu: Menu
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode) {}

            override fun onCreateActionMode(
                mode: ActionMode,
                menu: Menu
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onActionItemClicked(
                mode: ActionMode,
                item: MenuItem
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        })

    super.setOnClickListener { v ->
        setSelection(text.length)
        if (mClickListener != null) {
            mClickListener!!.onClick(v)
        }
    }
}

override fun setOnClickListener(l: OnClickListener) {
    mClickListener = l
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    val availableWidth = width - paddingRight - paddingLeft
    mCharSize = if (mSpace < 0) {
        (availableWidth / (mNumChars * 2 - 1))
    } else {
        (availableWidth - mSpace * (mNumChars - 1)) / mNumChars
    }

    var startX = paddingLeft.toFloat()
    val bottom = height.toFloat() - paddingBottom.toFloat()

    val text = text
    val textLength = text.length
    val textWidths = FloatArray(textLength)
    paint.getTextWidths(getText(), 0, textLength, textWidths)

    for (i in 0 until mNumChars.toInt()) {
        updateColorForLines(i == textLength)
        canvas.drawRoundRect(
            startX, 0f, startX + mCharSize, height.toFloat(), 5f, 5f, mLinesPaint
        )
        if (text.length > i) {
            val middle = startX + mCharSize / 2
            canvas.drawText(
                "******",
                i,
                i + 1,
                middle - textWidths[0] / 2,
                bottom - mLineSpacing,
                paint
            )
        }
        startX += if (mSpace < 0) {
            mCharSize * 2
        } else {
            mCharSize + mSpace
        }
    }
}

override fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence, start: Int, lengthBefore: Int, lengthAfter: Int) {
    if (mOnPinEnteredListener != null && text.length.toFloat() == mNumChars) {
            mOnPinEnteredListener!!.onPinEntered(text)
    }
}

fun setOnPinEnteredListener(l: OnPinEnteredListener) {
    mOnPinEnteredListener = l
}

interface OnPinEnteredListener {
    fun onPinEntered(str: CharSequence)
}
}
```

I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/building-a-pinentryedittext-in-android-5f2eddcae5d3

And I am getting behavior showed on picture: [image]

But I would like to have a behavior as shown here: [image]

How can I achieve that? How can I add those default dots/symbols? I tried adding it as a hint or default text, but it does not work because of my onDraw function

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you found already your solution. But here is how I would've done it:

The `PinEntryEditText` has an attribute you can set in the `.xml` file.
Adding this to the element will do the trick: `app:pinSingleCharHint="•"`

For more customisation check out the sample xml from [this](https://github.com/alphamu/PinEntryEditText) page